# google app engine app.yaml url handlers

Tags: google-app-engine

Im trying google app engine with python27.

How do I place my script in a different folder instead of placing under same folder with the app.yaml?

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: code/helloworld.app  ##### this give error #####
```

error message "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nick Johnson said: Make sure you reference by package name (`code.helloworld.app`). Also, make sure you have an empty `code/__init__.py` file.

Comment: What should the `__init__.py` contain?

Comment: Nothing, it should be empty.

Comment: @Matt Cooper Why is this necessary?  This helped me resolve my own issue, just not quite sure what this does.

Comment: It's for package inititalization. Not sure if this is the best article ever, but it talks about packages: http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 2.7 with multithreading, you need to reference by package name - `code.helloworld.app`.

Comment: @Peter What exactly did you change, and what happens? "Doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything about how it's failing.

Comment: I follow http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld.html , I only change the line "script: helloworld.app" to "script: code.helloworld.app" and move the "helloworld.py" under a subfolder and that doesn't work

Comment: @Peter "Doesn't work" still tells me nothing. What exception do you get? What goes wrong precisely?

Comment: I got the same problem, and after doing this, I got this error: `ImportError: No module named customers`