# Setting a Python Script Module with Classes on the Directory of Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

My question is similar to [google app engine app.yaml url handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147062/google-app-engine-app-yaml-url-handlers/9408925#comment19767116_9408925). But somehow, my question include classes.

I just recently transferred `customers.py` to `resources/customers.py`. `customers.py` contains a class named `CustomersResources`. Here is the app.yaml configuration:

```
- url: /resources/customers
  script: resources.CustomersResources.app
```

I got the following error:

```
ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name)) 
ImportError: <module 'resources' from 'C:\xampp\htdocs\pawnsoftware\trunk\pawnsoftware-0.0.1\resources.pyc'> has no attribute CustomersResources
```

**Edit:**

Since I have a conflict with the `resources` directory and `resources.py`. I have decided to remove the file `resources.py` from the root directory. Now, I have the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named resources
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your class is `resources.customers.CustomersResources` and your app is defined in the `resources.customers` module, so it would be `resources.customers.app`.

EDIT to reflect changes in question:
It seems you have both a resources folder and a `resources.py` file. They can't coexist. In your resources folder you need an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I just did this. It generates the same error. But, if you are going to check out the error, it seems it is saying that it has something to do with resources.pyc (resources.py)

Comment: Can you post all code, resources.py and customers.py (when did CustomersResources.py appear?), and the error you are getting.

Comment: No, what I am trying to say is, I separated the classes. CustomersResources class is located inside `root/resources/customers.py`. Resources is located inside `root/resources.py`. If you want to read the code of `CustomersResources`, you can read it from the link above, but it's not necessarily the content because I separated it. Yes, I will. Thank you. It maybe still non-functional though. But there it is.

Comment: I have changed the directory of `resources/customers.py` to `modules/customers.py` I don't get the previous error. But I got a different error. `ImportError: No module named modules`. Do I need to edit `resources.py` to accomodate `customers.py`? Btw, there is no `CustomersResources.py` file. Again, thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: the modules folder needs to have a __init__.py file inside of it. Please update qthe question with the changes youb have made and with the error you are getting.